# how to give where condition in magento customer selecting code

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I used this code to select all customer details

```
function getCustomers() {
    /* Magento's Mage.php path
     * Mage Enabler users may skip these lines
     */
    require_once ("../mysite/app/Mage.php");
    umask(0);
    Mage::app("default");
    /* Magento's Mage.php path */
    /* Get customer model, run a query */
    $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                  ->getCollection()

                  ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $result = array();
    foreach ($collection as $customer) {
        $result[] = $customer->toArray();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

But i alos want to check a field value...

That is thre have a column 'usertypecurrent ' in eav_attribute table.....

I need to check its value is 0.

That means select all customer its usertype is 0...

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **addAttributeToFilter** to filter results based on attribute values

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                  ->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('usertypecurrent', array('eq' =>0))
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```